# Attach a script to a particular node ID or view

Tags: theming

In Drupal 7, you can use the following code to attach a script to a particular content type:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['type'] == 'INSERT_CONTENT_TYPE') {

        // include javascript
        drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . 'INSERT_SCRIPT');

      }

    }
```

What code do you need to use to attach a script to a particular Node ID or a specific View?

I have tried swapping `variables['type']` with various items, but none seem to work.

Comment: Where are you adding this code? Some preprocess function?

Comment: Hi I have updated my answer to make it clearer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Node ID:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['nid'] == 'INSERT_NODE_ID') {
    // include javascript
    drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . 'INSERT_SCRIPT');
  }
}
```

View:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view(&$variables){
  if ($variables['name'] == 'INSERT_VIEW_MACHINE_NAME') {
    // include javascript
    drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . 'INSERT_SCRIPT');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This gets the bounty as it is the cleanest solution and works for both node and view.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need a "/" before "INSERT_SCRIPT". (e.g. /scripts/custom.js)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using D6. Try using [JS injector](http://drupal.org/project/js_injector) to insert custom javascript to a page or view.

Comment: Hi I am using Drupal 7 and would like to do it without an extra module.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question, why not display your script accoring the alias of your view or your node or view? (also is possible using the node ID)

I have tested these functions with `_preprocess_node` (nodes) an also with `_preprocess_page` (for views and nodes) in Drupal `6` and `7`.

this is for node with ID with `_preprocess_node`:

```
function seven_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    if(isset($_GET['q'])){
        $nodeID = '9';
          if(arg(1) == $nodeID){
              drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/test.js');
          } 
      }
}
```

this is for node with alias with `_preprocess_node`:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    if(isset($_GET['q'])){
          $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
          if(preg_match('#test_page#', $path)){
              drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/test.js');
          } 
      }
}
```

and this function with `_preprocess_page` will be useful for nodes and/or views (alias):

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if(isset($_GET['q'])){
          $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
          if(preg_match('#test_page#', $path)){
              drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/test.js');
          } 
      }
}
```

this last function is only to show an example of a function seeking alias of your view/node or node ID:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if(isset($_GET['q'])){
        $script = '/test.js';//script name
        $currentPath = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);//current alias
        $targetPath = '#test_view#';//alias to match (delimiter is #), is for example of your view's page.
        $targetNodeID = '9';//node ID to match
          if(arg(1) == $targetNodeID || preg_match($targetPath, $currentPath)){
              drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . $script);
          }
     }
}
```

I hope information be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node($node) {
    if ($node->nid == INSERT_NODE_ID) {
        // include javascript
        drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . 'INSERT_SCRIPT');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nothing worked for me, so i checked with 'preprocess' hook, that works fine as follows:-

```
function MYMODULE-or-THEME_preprocess(){
    if(isset($_GET['q'])){
    $nodeID = '232'; //NODE ID TO CHECK
          if(arg(1) == $nodeID){              
     drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE').'/js/myscript.js');
         } 
    }
}
```