# How do I add javascript to a node or block

Tags: 7, nodes, javascript, blocks

I've made a cost calculator script and want to use it on my Drupal 7 site.

I heard to use `drupal_add_js`, but I don't know in what context.

Answer (score 8):

Use a function in the template.php file: `yoursite.com/sites/all/themes/YOUR_THEME/template.php`

Add JS file in a block:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {  
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') .'/scripts/path');
}
```

Add JS file to ***one*** page or node:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['nid'] == 'INSERT_NODE_ID') {
     drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') .'/scripts/path');
  }
}
```

Add JS file to a content type:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['type'] == 'INSERT_CONTENT_TYPE') {
       drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/scripts/path');
  }
}
```

Add JS file to a view:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_views_view(&$variables){
  if ($variables['name'] == 'INSERT_VIEW_MACHINE_NAME') {
    // include javascript
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/scripts/path');
  }
}
```

As mentioned by @Pierpaolo Cira, you could always replace `MY_THEME` with `MY_MOUDLE`. To get the path to your module you would have to use `drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module')`.

**Note**: `MY_THEME` and `MY_MODULE` needs to be lowered case if your module or theme name is lowercased. (E.g. `MY_THEME` would be replaced with `zen` if zen)

[Source](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12725/attach-a-script-to-a-particular-node-id-or-view)

Comment: This reply should be the accepted one

Comment: I would add (this is not evident from the reply) that these hooks work also for modules that provides JS behaviours in the visualisation... so (e.g.) YOUR_THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) can also be YOUR_MODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables).

Answer (score 3):

You can add the js **inside a module** :

Create the module and put inside the mymodule.module

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mymodule.js');
```

or **in the theme**:

in the .info file

```
name = My theme
description = Theme developed by me.
core = 7.x
engine = phptemplate

scripts[] = mytheme.js
```

or in a preprocess_page function

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (true) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/mytheme.js');
    $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js(); // necessary in D7?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to get the path from Drupal, and you have to put the code in the form function;

```
function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state) {

... some of your forms goes here

    $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/myscript.js';

  return $form;
```

Also add your javascript between the code below

```
(function($)  {
  function mymodule_function(context)  {

  // from here

  // paste your code in here

  // till here

  }

  Drupal.behaviors.custommodule = {
    attach: function(context)  {
      mymodule_function(context);
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Where would I put this?

Comment: please check this link http://drupal.org/node/121997

Answer (score 2):

Use function in template.php

Add JS file in block:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {  
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') .'/mytheme.js', 'file');
}
```

Add JS file in page or node:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {  
     drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') .'/mytheme.js', 'file');

}
```

Comment: Adding the js in hook_init() in custom module will also make it available elsewhere to use, as example
function mymodulename_init() {  
         drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodulename') .'/mytheme.js');
}

Answer (score -1):

if your script is saved as .js you can add it like that in html.tpl.php:

```
<?php drupal_add_js('location/of/my/script/my_script.js'); ?>
```

more info  [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

OR

```
<script src="location/of/my/script/my_script.js"></script>
```

in your block or node body (make sure that you select format that does not filter JavaScript i.e. "PHP code")

Comment: Do I insert this in the node edit form? Is it fine to put the .js file in the sites folder?

Comment: yes - you can put it in node edit form if you wish. just remember to enable in "PHP filter" in modules' core section and set "text format" to "PHP code" in node edit form; and yes - you can put .js in sites folder.

Comment: Followed your instructions and this did not work for me.

Comment: did you clear cache? another solution which I do not recommend but it probably will work is rather than using drupal_add_js is simply 
[link]<script src="location/of/my/script/my_script.js"></script>

Comment: I need to correct myself: By the time Drupal reaches the block data, the contents of <head> have already been generated, this means that calling drupal_add_js through the block's body field will have no effect. Please use <script> as described above or put drupal_add_js in html.tpl.php of your theme

Comment: I've added <?php drupal_add_js ('/sites/all/themes/corporateclean/js/feecalculator.js'); ?> to the html.tpl.php file. Do I call the file in the node edit form using <script src="/sites/all/themes/corporateclean/js/feecalculator.js'"></script> ?

Comment: ok - so what drupal_add_js does is prit to <head>: <script src="whatever you put it the bracket of that function"></script>. this means that you dont need to add it again. you can always check if it worked by looking at the source of the page. if for some reason it didnt - just add  <script src="/sites/all/themes/corporateclean/js/feecalculator.js"></script> straight to your block's body. Just one more thing - i noticed that you have redundant single quote quote feecalculator.js **'** " - the one after .js

Comment: Can I use this "<script src="location/of/my/script/my_script.js"></script> " inside a block in drupal 8 ?

Comment: It is considered to be a really bad practice to add JS files in template files direclty unless you ran out of other options