# How to attach a JS library to page or block with #attached?

Tags: 7

I have seen something like the following document for forms:

```
$form['myelement']['#attached']['libraries_load'][] = array('myAwesomeLibrary');
```

However, this does not work in render arrays for pages or blocks.  At least, not in Drupal 7. When attaching a JS library to a render array in a page or block, should I use the 'libraries_load' or 'library' key within the '`#attached`' array?  Neither seem to work.

Of course, it's possible to use the 'js' key along with libraries_get_path, but I'm not sure that's best practice for Drupal 7, and it doesn't really take advantage of the path in hook_libraries_info.

Comment: Ah, I missed that last bit when typing up my answer. What do you mean by "it doesn't really take advantage of the path in hook_libraries_info"?

Comment: Annnd answer deleted. I need more sleep. :-/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add javascript to a node or block](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68696/how-do-i-add-javascript-to-a-node-or-block)

Comment: Question about Library/Libraries API seems different than a generic question about adding JS...

Answer (score 3):

This might be a simple case of misunderstanding. The difference between `libraries_load` and `library` #attached keys can be confusing.

`['#attached']['libraries_load']` is for libraries defined through `hook_libraries_info` which is in turn a part of the [Libraries API](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module. If a module has defined a hook `hook_libraries_info` but your installation doesn't have the Libraries API module installed, then that library will never load. The `libraries_load` key of #attached will not fire for the same reason. Ideally though, this module with the `hook_libraries_info` should have a dependency on the Libraries API module if it was written correctly.

`['#attached']['library']` is for libraries defined through drupal core library api [`hook_library`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_library/7). This should always work without any additional modules, provided you've defined a `hook_library` in your module (and not `hook_libraries_info`)

Hope this helps you get a clearer idea of what's exactly wrong. You can't have these interchanging, and just trying `libraries_load` or `library` randomly to see if they work. Both require a certain prerequisite (see above) to function correctly.

Comment: If you answer questions marked "possible duplicate", please also comment under question and tell why you don't think it's a duplicate. It's not a rule it requirement, but if you have a reason, sharing it may help to keep question open.

Comment: There's nothing about libraries in that Q&A

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this that come to my mind. The first is registering a `hook_library()` within a custom module. This will allow you to include multiple JS/CSS files.

However, a more common approach would be:

**BLOCK**: `drupal_add_js()` or `drupal_add_css()` in the `hook_block_view()` implementation.

**PAGE**: If this is a page you are defining through code, you could use the BLOCK implementation above **or** you could do a `template_preprocess_page()`.

hook_library: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_library/7

drupal_add_js: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7

drupal_add_css: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7

template_preprocess_page: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7