# How can I load a javascript file into a Drupal 7 page using the Code per Node module?

Tags: 7, javascript

What is the syntax for including Javascript from a remote location into a Drupal 7 page using the Code per node module?

I have seen this code `drupal_add_js('path/to/somescript.js')` at [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7 | Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722), but it seems that is not for use on Drupal 7.

What would be the Drupal 7 equivalent?

Comment: The linked documentation is the correct documentation for D7 core.  You are trying to use a contrib module, so you need to look at the contrib module's documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Code per node module is  intented to use to have a custom JS for each node. The JS code must be placed inline, in the node add / edit form. You have [this tutorial](http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/webinar-code-node) to see how it works.

If you want to add the same js to a specific content type you can create a module custom where you invoke [preprocess node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7.x) hook:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['type'] == 'INSERT_CONTENT_TYPE') {
       drupal_add_js('path/to/somescript.js');
  }
}
```

You can also do this in a custom theme, there are examples in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68696/how-do-i-add-javascript-to-a-node-or-block).

If you want see a module with [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x) examples and a nice documenttion, you can see the module **js_example** , which is a module inside [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) 7.x.

Answer (score 0):

try this just change the link to whatever external library you are trying to import  : `drupal_add_js('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ally.js/1.0.1/ally.min.js', array('type' => 'external', 'scope' => 'footer'));`

take a look at this : [drupal.org/node/905994](https://www.drupal.org/node/905994)